# Time series forecast on daily data to forecast future 30 days

Tags: r, time-series

I am building a time series forecasting model to forecast my future volume of sales based on historic data collected on daily basis from September 2017 to September 2019. 
I have transformed my data suitable for time series forecasting. 
I was wondering if there is an automated way of finding seasonality and trend in my data and based on the results I can choose which model to use and their components as well?

I have put my data in this post. 
Could any of you please help me working out with this?

Also could any of you please let me know if I need to concentrate only on day of the year or weekly or monthly for building my time series object.

```
timeSeriesObjW = ts(ENGLISH$Usual,start=c(2017,09,20),frequency=7)
fitW <- tbats(timeSeriesObjW)
seasonalW <- !is.null(fitW$seasonal)
seasonalW

#Daily Fit

timeSeriesObjD = ts(ENGLISH$Usual,start=c(2017,09,20),frequency=365.25)
fitD <- tbats(timeSeriesObjD)
seasonalD <- !is.null(fitD$seasonal)
seasonalD

fitW <- arima(timeSeriesObjW, order=c(1, 0, 1))
fitW

fitD <- arima(timeSeriesObjD, order=c(1, 0, 0))
fitD


#Automated way of detecting if there exists any seasonal pattern in our data
x <- ts(ENGLISH$Usual, frequency=365/7)
fit <- tbats(x)
seasonal <- !is.null(fit$seasonal)
seasonal


library(fma)
fit1 <- ets(ENGLISH$Usual)
fit2 <- ets(ENGLISH$Usual,model="ANN")

deviance <- 2*c(logLik(fit1) - logLik(fit2))
df <- attributes(logLik(fit1))$df - attributes(logLik(fit2))$df
#P value
1-pchisq(deviance,df)
```

$p$-value I get is 0

Comment: The standard `decompose` function in R is not suitable in this case? (see `?decompose`). Concerning the frequency of the data this really depends on what you think is relevant. My layman's view on this is that daily sales data maybe a bit much while you lose a lot of information aggregating to monthly level; so weekly might be the best option.

Comment: "I have put my data in this post"     .... where is the data ?